# Changing active signal resolution only changes desktop resolution?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Windows is trolling me again. Today I got on and one of my two 1920x1080 ViewSonic monitors has decided it's a Dell AW3418DW. It won't display anything, displaying the "Out of Range" message. To which I found out I had to go to Advanced Display Properties and change the Active Signal Resolution. That page looks like this:

[3440x1440 when it should be 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVrN9.png)

So I click on the advanced properties and go to "List All Modes" to change it. But it's already listed at 1920x1080??

[List All Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z2Rn.png)

Interestingly here it *is* detected as the correct "Generic PnP Monitor".  If I change it to anything else, it just changes the Desktop Resolution *not* the Active Signal Resolution.

[Active signal resolution changes desktop resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVMjM.png)

Very odd. But I've come to expect nothing less from Windows!

Exact question because a bot said it was unclear: **Monitor is "Out of Range" and changing active signal resolution actually only changes desktop resolution? How do I fix this so I can use the monitor?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you certain this is Windows.  I have a brand new View Sonic Monitor in the basement that I junked. It mis-behaved horribly. I replaced it with a Lenovo monitor that works fine.